# Resizing tab contents

Tags: java, javafx

I have a tabpane where tabs are loaded dynamically. Each tab has an anchorpane as its content.
This works great except for one little detail: when I resize the main application, the tab content is not resized.

So suppose I maximize my application, the tab content retains its "small" size. How can I trigger a resize on the tab content considering its root is an anchorpane?

I am a newcomer to the javafx world and in my ignorance I have tried wrapping the anchorpane in an hbox and setting that as the content of the tab to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is example of how to resize component but the idea is the same.

```
    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
    rec.widthProperty().bind(stackPane.widthProperty().subtract(50));
    rec.heightProperty().bind(stackPane.heightProperty().subtract(50));
```

You have to get the size of the main stage and with `.bind(stackPane.heightProperty().subtract(50));` you can shrink dynamically the size.

But I'm new to this technology and someone more experienced can give you more accurate answer.

Comment: This was my first thought as well but I think it can't be done as the width/heigh property is read only

Answer (score 0):

Put AnchorPane constraints to the TabPane (not Tabs, beware) so that it resizes itself according to its container AnchorPane.

If you are using SceneBuilder, Layout section of the TabPane instance would help you. If you create also the TabPane dynamically, you can set this constaints as `AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(theTabPane, ...)`, `AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(theTabPane, ...)`, etc.

Comment: This does not seem to work. According to the spec I think the anchors are used to anchor child elements to the anchorpane, not the anchorpane to its parent.

Comment: With 'container AnchorPane', I meant the container of the TabPane, not the container of the content of a single Tab. So If you put the aforementioned constraints, the tabPane will resize itself, and hence the tab contents, (at least I hope so).

Answer (score 0):

I currently have a working solution though I'm pretty sure it's not the cleanest way to do this:

```
            final Pane root = loader.getRoot();
            tbsCore.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number arg1, Number newValue) {
                    root.setPrefWidth(newValue.doubleValue());
                }
            });
            tbsCore.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number arg1, Number newValue) {
                    root.setPrefHeight(newValue.doubleValue());
                }
            });
```

Note that "root" is the pane I want to put in the tab while "tbsCore" is the TabPane.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said, I understood you had the same problem I faced today! Making the `TabPane` fill the space of the window was easy, but the content wasn't resizing.

Some tips to find out what is happening:

- Set different background colors (or borders) for each `Node`, to see which `Node`s grow and which don't. When resizing, you may see, for instance, that the `AnchorPane` is resizing too, but the content isn't.
- Look for any `preferredWidth`, `preferredHeight`, `preferredSize`, `maxWidth`, `maxHeight` or `maxSize` that might prevent the `Node` to grow.
- Look if you need to set a special property for the `Node` or its children to grow. Some examples are:

  - [`ScrollPane.setFitToWidth(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setFitToWidth-boolean-) or [`ScrollPane.setFitToHeight(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setFitToHeight-boolean-)
  - [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)'s Column and Row Constraints, or [`GridPane.setFillWidth(child, true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setFillWidth-javafx.scene.Node-java.lang.Boolean-) or [`GridPane.setFillHeight(child, true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setFillHeight-javafx.scene.Node-java.lang.Boolean-)
  - [`VBox.setVgrow(child, Priority.ALWAYS)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#setVgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-) or [`VBox.setFillWith(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#setFillWidth-boolean-)
  - [`HBox.setHgrow(child, Priority.ALWAYS)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setHgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-) or [`HBox.setFillHeight(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setFillHeight-boolean-)
- Lastly, look for a hidden `Node` in your code! For example, I was adding a `GridPane` to the `Tab` with the following code:

  ```
  Tab tab = new Tab("Tab Title", new ScrollPane(myHugeGridPane));
  ```

  and this "hidden" ScrollPane was the problem.